# MatPlot lib keeps giving "out of range error"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im trying to make a pokedex where it stores all the names and stats of the pokemon in a .csv file and reads off of that when called. It should also show an image of the pokemon when called.
The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob
import natsort

# reading the images dataset
dir1 = r"C:\Users\yash1\Desktop\pokedex\pokemon_images"
path1 = os.path.join(dir1, '*g')
files = glob.glob(path1)
files1 = natsort.natsorted(files, reverse=False)
imag = []
for x in files1:
    img = plt.imread(x)
    imag.append(img)

# reading the details dataset
data = pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv')
print("Pokedex\n")
print("Welcome Pokemon Lovers\n")
print("Search for a pokemon\n")
df1 =input("<A>Search by pokemon name\n<B>Search by pokemon ID\n(select A or B)\n")
df1.upper()
if(df1=="A"):
    print("Enter the name of the pokemon")
    name = input()
    name.lower().strip()
    dt = data[:].where(data['pokemon']==name)
    st = dt[dt['id'].notnull()]
    idx = dt.index[dt['pokemon'] == name]
    if idx > 721:
        exit(0)
    plt.imshow(imag[idx[1]])
    plt.axis("off")  # turns off axes
    plt.axis("tight")  # gets rid of white border
    plt.axis("image")  # square up the image instead of filling the "figure" space
    plt.show()
elif(df1=="B"):
    print("Enter the ID of the pokemon")
    ID = int(input())
    tt = data[:].where(data['id']==ID)
    idx1 = tt.index[tt['id']==ID]
    qt = tt[tt['id'].notnull()]
    for i in qt.columns:
        print(i," : ",qt[i][idx1[0]])
    if idx1>721:
        exit(0)
    #plt.imshow(imag[idx1[0]])
    plt.axis("off")   # turns off axes
    plt.axis("tight")  # gets rid of white border
    plt.axis("image")  # square up the image instead of filling the "figure" space
    plt.show()
```

when I run it it gives me an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/pythonProject/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    plt.imshow(imag[idx[1]])
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4604, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

How do I fix the axis bounds, I even replaced the brackets with "0" and it still didn't work.

Comment: What's the output of `idx`? It's out of range by using `1`.

Comment: the first element of a sequence `x` in python is accessed as `x[0]`. The last element is `x[-1]`

Comment: I replaced the two values with 1 and -1, the `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` this is the code I have
```for i in qt.columns:
        print(i," : ",qt[i][idx1[1]])
    if idx1>721:
        exit(0)
    plt.imshow(imag[idx1[-1]])
```